# How to add dot view to the text in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I had used UIStackView for cell design. Now  I have to add a yellow dot view beside the text "Inprocess". How we can do it?

[image]

```
let backView = UIView(color: AppColor.appWhite, cornerRadius: 18)

lazy var advanceStack = VerticalStackView(arrangedSubViews: [SalaryadvanceLabel, $99advanceValue], spacing: 3, distribution: .fillEqually)
lazy var StatusStack = VerticalStackView(arrangedSubViews: [Inprocesslabel, timelabel], spacing: 3, distribution: .fillEqually)
    
lazy var infoStack = HorizontalStackView(arrangedSubViews: [advanceStack, StatusStack], spacing: 10, distribution: .fillEqually)

let indicator: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(color: AppColor.appGreen, cornerRadius: 3)
    view.constraintWidth(constant: 6)
    view.constraintHeight(constant: 6)
    return view
}()
    
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = AppColor.appBackground
    selectionStyle = .none
    setupView()
    indicator.isHidden = true
}

private func setupView() {
    addSubview(backView)
    backView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12))

    backView.addSubview(infoStack)
    infoStack.anchor(top: nil, leading: backView.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: backView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20))
    infoStack.centerYInSuperview()

    backView.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.anchor(top: infoStack.bottomAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: chargeValue.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
}
```

Comment: Many possibilities: use an attributed string for the label with the dot in there; create a custom view with a coloured dot and the label, and add that to your vertical stackview; create a horizontal stackview with a dot and a label and add that to the vertical stackview; ....

Comment: • <-- Maybe use this character with style just before your text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code and added it to the UIStackView. Problem solved.

```
let StatusDot = UILabel(text: "\u{2022}" , color: AppColor.appBlack, font: Helvetica.bold, size: 40, alignment: .right)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this with an `attributedText` with a dot like character (as already suggested in the comments)

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "• In process")
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemYellow
]
attributedText.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))


inProcessLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```